# When I remove data, code will stuck

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I have excel sheet with dropdown list and when I choose anything from the list
[image]

macro will vlookup for requested value. But when I want to remove values from those cells, that I select them and press delete, it will show me "#N/A" and the excel is frozen, I cant do anything. Could you advise me, how can I avoid it, please?
[image]

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change()
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim selectedNa As Integer, selectedNum As Integer

    selectedNa = Target.Value
    If Target.Column = 10 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, ActiveSheet.Range("dropdown"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            Target.Value = selectedNum
        Else: Exit Sub
        End If
    Else: Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the missing ByVal Target As Range in Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) a copy "mistake"? Also disable events in order to prevent the code to run multiple times.

Comment: And why did you declare Target in the Sub itself?

Comment: I just didnt know, that I should declare it inside of brackets

Comment: If you use it like that it cannot work unless the sub is not in the sheet module. You will get a compiler error.

Comment: I have the code in Microsoft Excel Objects - Sheet1 and it works, until I want to remove two or more cells together. If I want to remove cell by cell, then it works without any issues.

Comment: No as said if the code is the same as you posted it cannot work. You will get a compiler error!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 Dim selectedNa As Long, selectedNum As Variant

 If Target.Column = 10 And Not IsEmpty(Target) Then  'selectedNa <> vbNullString Then '

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    On Error GoTo errhand

    selectedNa = Target.Value

    selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, ActiveSheet.Range("dropdown"), 2, False)

     If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then

         Target.Value = selectedNum

     End If

     Application.EnableEvents = True

 End If

 Exit Sub

errhand:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped That'll learn me for rushing. Have I got the enable events right?

Comment: IMO not quite because in case Target.value is not of type long the code will run into an error and events will not be enabled again.

Comment: @Storax i feel like i have been heavy handed with the enableevents

Comment: Thanks guys! Unfortunately, it is still the same :(

Comment: But it is working if you select a value from the list? Your original code cannot have worked at all!

Comment: why data type is selectedNa btw?

Comment: It is, but my code works as well. There are no differents at the end of the day . I mean, that the vlookup works for both, but removing does not.

Answer (score 0):

Change your posted code to

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

Dim selectedNa As Integer, selectedNum As Integer

    On Error GoTo EH

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    selectedNa = target.Value

    If target.Column = 10 Then
        selectedNum = Application.VLookup(selectedNa, ActiveSheet.Range("dropdown"), 2, False)
        If Not IsError(selectedNum) Then
            target.Value = selectedNum
        End If
    End If

EH:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
End Sub
```

The code HAS TO be put into the sheet module. 
Have a look at the immediate window after you have changed or deleted a value in your sheet.

Comment: selectedNum  has to a variant if you intend to catch no-match errors with iserror.

Comment: I just took the TO's code, removed the unneccessary Exit Subs and added  simple arror handling in order to get at the original problem. But the TO keeps telling that his code is working fine although it cannot even compile :-(

Comment: Yeah, we either aren't getting all the code or something else is going on. `selectedNa = target.Value` doesn't seem to work as an integer looking at the op's image either.

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like this is what you want, based on the information provided:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim CheckCells As Range
    Dim ChangedCell As Range

    Set CheckCells = Intersect(Me.Columns(10), Target)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not CheckCells Is Nothing Then
        For Each ChangedCell In CheckCells.Cells
            If Len(ChangedCell.Value) > 0 And WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Me.Range("dropdown"), ChangedCell.Value) > 0 Then
                ChangedCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ChangedCell.Value, Me.Range("dropdown").Resize(, 2), 2, False)
            End If
        Next ChangedCell
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```